# rowSettingsTemplate.js Not Found

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to implement row highlights in `sap.ui.table.Table` but in the Web IDE console, I see this error:

> found in negative cache: 'sap/m/rowSettingsTemplate.js' from
>   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.46.7/resources/sap/m/rowSettingsTemplate.js:
>    404 - error undefined

I get the [code from this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.RowHighlights/code/View.view.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two issues:**

1. The namespace for the `rowSettingsTemplate` node is not properly assigned. Either your default namespace (`xmlns="..."`) points to `sap.m` or you added incorrectly the prefix e.g. `<m:` whereas the namespace `m` points to `sap.m`. Eitherway, the `rowSettingsTemplate` should be coming from `sap.ui.table`.
2. Another, bigger issue: The aggregation `rowSettingsTemplate`, as well as the Control `sap.ui.table.RowSettings`, is only available since UI5 version 1.48<sup>1</sup>. Your current UI5 version is 1.46.7.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See [Changelog](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/b43f3540203ba59d207c2d80bb72ff33b6a65dbd/src/sap.ui.table/test/sap/ui/table/relnotes/changes-1.48.json#L11-L16), corresponding [commit](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/f9c849df7de3de7ca800020e044b2ae81f2252d7), and [What's New in OpenUI5 1.48](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2818f800e7424c5c91dbd495f8cb757b)